permanent alias for gcc with flags
how can i set a permanent alias for "gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror" in powershell ?
I tried
function cc { gcc "-Wall -Wextra -Werror" }

but it didn't work. Please help me


if those are arguments for gcc then remove the quotes. function cc { gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror } otherwise the external command interprets those 3 arguments a single one

I recommend you to follow the instructions in this topic, it's telling how to create permanent aliases for Windows Powershell, so you can use it as a base to make your custom alias for GCC with flags.

This strikes me as an excellent comment, but lacking in substance for an answer; being primarily a link to an existing question, you may want to flag this question as a duplicate.

Another option may be a bashrc equivalent: https://superuser.com/questions/1090141/does-powershell-have-any-sort-of-bashrc-equivalent
